# manuel paper format setting

Tags: fontsize, layout, scrartcl

I use this MWE and it works just fine. The paper is orientated as I wish

```
\documentclass[11pt,paper=180mm:320mm, xcolor=dvipsnames]{scrartcl}
\geometry{left=25mm,right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=20mm}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

But if I change the fontsize to 14pt everything changes. If I compile the file like this the orientation of the paper changes from 180mm:320mm to 320mm:180mm.

```
\documentclass[14pt,paper=180mm:320mm, xcolor=dvipsnames]{scrartcl}
\geometry{left=25mm,right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=20mm}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

As you see, the ONLY change is the fontsize. Do you have any idea why this is the case?

Comment: Ok, well, I found a work around and I can use \begin{landscape} ...  \end{landscape} but it is still very strange and not that handy to use ...

Comment: your document produces two screenfulls of warnings from scratcl that the options are obsolete and inconsistently set

Comment: Package scrartcl Warning: You've used deprecated option \`14pt'.
(scrartcl)                Usage of this option indicates an old document
(scrartcl)                and changes compatibility level using
(scrartcl)                \`fontsize=14pt,version=first,
(scrartcl)                enabledeprecatedfontcommands' that may result
(scrartcl)                in further warnings.
(scrartcl)                If you don't want this, you should simply
(scrartcl)                replace option \`14pt' by \`fontsize=14pt'.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Interesstingly I didn´t get any warnings, but now it works just fine! And it was an easy fix ;)

Comment: you must have had warnings, look in the log file (you may be using an editor that hides warnings from you, which unfortunately is not uncommon)

Comment: Yes, you were right. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @montarenbici, not sure, if you should post this, but why not considering to answer your own question with the solution you found? // BTW, why would you need such a large font, for what purpose?

Comment: @MS-SPO I want to make a beamer presentation for YouTube an there I wish to have a bigger font size. But there are actually a few other problems that I need to overcome at first. For example I should have the presentation exported as .jpg or .pgn files an that is more a obstacle ...

Comment: @montarenbici, ok, so why don‘t you use the beaner class, and where needed \large, \huge etc.?

Comment: @MS-SPO I considered it, but if I use beamer, I can also only export pdf-files. I didn´t find any way to export .jpg or .pgn files.

Comment: @montarenbici, a few options: 1) google `split pdf pagewise to jpg` to find some programs and online converters. 2) save pages manually as image from Techmaker editor. 3) generate pdf, split into pages.pdf, convert e.g. by imagemagick; this one is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60697059. There are certainly more ways to do it

Comment: (It's Texmaker, BTW ...)